# Type convert issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT
    MIN(RIGHT(LEFT(REPLOG_TRANSACTION, 406), 20)) 
FROM
    t_replog_input 
WHERE
    REPLOG_TRANSACTION LIKE 'insert%'
```

This query is returning a `varchar` value: `20020000000000015015`

This works correctly, I am able to print value which was converted to `float` from `varchar`:

```
DECLARE @min float;
BEGIN
    SET @min = CONVERT(float, 30020000000000015015);
    PRINT 'min value: ' + CAST (@min as varchar(1000));
END;
```

After replacing `varchar` value "20020000000000015015" by select statement I have this query:

```
DECLARE
    @min float;
BEGIN
    SET @min = CONVERT(float, SELECT MIN(RIGHT(LEFT(REPLOG_TRANSACTION, 406), 20)) 
                              FROM t_replog_input 
                              WHERE REPLOG_TRANSACTION LIKE 'insert%');
    PRINT  'min value: ' + CAST (@min as varchar(1000));
END;
```

and I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Can you please advise?

Thank you

Update:
This works ok, I updated my code to do all job and added REPLACE function to replace the min value by max unique value in the loop but seems not be performed:

```
DECLARE
    @min float,
    @licznik int = 1,
    @maxnumber float;
BEGIN
      SET @maxnumber ='20020000000000015020';  -- max srv nunmmber +1
        WHILE @licznik < 4
            BEGIN
                 SET @min=CONVERT(float, (select min(right(left(REPLOG_TRANSACTION,406),20)) from t_replog_input where REPLOG_TRANSACTION like 'insert%'));
                 UPDATE 
                    t_replog_input
                 SET 
                    REPLOG_TRANSACTION = REPLACE (REPLOG_TRANSACTION, @min , @maxnumber)
                 PRINT  'min value: ' + CAST (@min as varchar(1000));
                 PRINT  'licznik: ' + CAST (@licznik as varchar(1000));
                 PRINT  'max_number: ' + CAST (@maxnumber as varchar(1000));
                 SET @licznik = @licznik + 1;
                 SET @maxnumber = @maxnumber +1;
           END;
END;
```

After playing thisn updated sql code and :

```
select right(left(REPLOG_TRANSACTION,406),20) from t_replog_input where REPLOG_TRANSACTION like 'insert%'
```

I receive output the same as before playing it:

```
20020000000000015015
20020000000000015016
20020000000000015017
```

when it should be 20020000000000015020, 20020000000000015021 and 20020000000000015022

Comment: When you use a query to set a scalar value, you must enclose that query in parentheses. As already indicated, the general syntax is "set x = (your query);"

Comment: As an alternative to the correction @SMor pointed out, you could change `SET` to `SELECT` for the scalar value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can't examine your issue, but I would suggest the problem is your SQL expression needs to be enclosed in parenthesis:

```
set @min=
    Convert(
        float, ( 
            select Min(right(left(REPLOG_TRANSACTION,406),20))
            from t_replog_input 
            where REPLOG_TRANSACTION like 'insert%'
        )
    )
```

Comment: Why REPLACE function does not work in my loop above? min and maxnumber variables are correctly increased within WHILE loop.

Comment: @Mateusz that's different to the question asked - the above addresses your original question, please ask a new question if needed but don't move the goal posts!